# Formula For Calculating an Outcome with multiple random inputs

Tags: statistics

I am making a spreadsheet to track the probability of the number of outs for a baseball team based on the on base percentage of the players. I am trying to do this in google sheets but I feel like I am missing a simple formula to at least calculate the result of one out.

For Example

| OBP | Out % | 1 Out | 2 Out | 3 Out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.4 | 0.6 | =0.6 | 0 | 0 |
| 0.3 | 0.7 | =0.4$\cdot$0.7 + 0.3$\cdot$0.6 | =0.6$\cdot$0.7 | 0 |
| 0.2 | 0.8 | =0.4$\cdot$0.3$\cdot$0.8 + 0.4$\cdot$0.7$\cdot$0.2 + 0.6$\cdot$0.3$\cdot$0.2 | =0.4$\cdot$0.7$\cdot$0.8 + 0.6$\cdot$0.7$\cdot$0.2 + 0.6$\cdot$0.3$\cdot$0.8 | 0.6$\cdot$0.7$\cdot$0.8 |

I was looking at the binomial distribution but I don't know if that is the correct formula to reach for or how to apply to to more than one random outcome. I don't know if this is the correct stack exchange to ask but I was hoping I could get some guidance. Thanks.

Comment: Expressions like 0.40.30.8 are hard to read with the confusion between the decimal point and a multiplication sign.  We use \cdot in MathJax to get a centered multiplication dot.  We would then see $0.4\cdot0.3\cdot0.8$, which is much easier.

Comment: Thanks I used `$\cdot$` to update my example inline.

Comment: Your formulas are all correct.  You can use references to the OBP column to make it update automatically.

Comment: I can simplify it by using the product P(A2:An)*(B2/A2+B3/A3+B4/A4....Bn/An) but I was wondering if there is a specific formula I could use? Or what the formula would be called in statistics so that I could look up a more general formula. It starts to get very tedious entering in each cell.

Comment: @RossMillikan Is there a formula to use where I don't have to enter in the whole polynomial?

Comment: Not that I know of.  You only have nine terms to enter in the most complicated one.

Comment: 3 outs per an inning and there is 9 innings is 27 outs... so that's 9 terms but across all those combinations it gets a little much

Comment: I don't understand then what you want to do.  Often you could make one region for an inning, then combine innings in another region.  Everything so far was one inning.  The other thing is forget what you don't need to know.  What question are you trying to answer?  Does it matter if there are six outs among the first nine batters which batters made out?

Comment: By the time I get to the 9th batter for two outs that's 9 choose 2 which gives me 9 variables. That's summing up 36 products each with 9 terms.

Comment: It's like tossing a coin whose probability keeps changing and I want to find out how many times it comes up heads. In the Example above the first toss comes up heads 40% of the time, 2nd toss 30%, 3rd toss 20% and then it keeps going. I want to know the probability for it turning up heads.